# Dserialise xml when it contains a list of elements using XmlSerialiser

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I've been given some XML that I am wanting to deserialize into a class object however I'm having trouble with items that appear to be a list i.e. subscription_product and product_id.  Basically there is only ever 0 records in my Associates and Products list

Here is an example of the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" "encoding=utf-8"?>
  <subscription_product consultant_end_user_id="4" farm_id="6" 
     farm_name="Farm Name"   
     farmer_end_user_id="5" 
     subscription_expiry="2014-01-01" 
     subscription_id="7">
    <associate_end_user_id>1</associate_end_user_id>
    <associate_end_user_id>2</associate_end_user_id>
    <associate_end_user_id>3</associate_end_user_id>
    <product_id>8</product_id>
    <product_id>9</product_id>
    <product_id>10</product_id>
  </subscription_product>
```

Here is class object that maps to this

```
[XmlRoot("subscription_product")]
public class Subscription
{
    public Subscription()
    {
        Associates = new List<int>();
        Products = new List<int>();
    }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="subscription_expiry")]
    public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "subscription_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "farmer_end_user_id")]
    public int FarmOwnerId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "farm_name")]
    public string FarmName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "consultant_end_user_id")]
    public int ConsultantId { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "subscription_product")]
    [XmlArrayItem("associate_end_user_id", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public List<int> Associates { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "product_id")]
    public List<int> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code that is being used to deserialize it

```
public class SchemaReader : ISchemaReader
{

    public T Deserialise<T>(string input) where T : class
    {
        return Deserialise<T>(input, string.Empty);
    }

    public T Deserialise<T>(string input, string elementRootName) where T : class
    {
        return (T)Deserialise(input, typeof(T), elementRootName);
    }

    public object Deserialise(string input, Type objectType)
    {
        return Deserialise(input, objectType, string.Empty);
    }

    public object Deserialise(string input, Type objectType, string elementRootName)
    {
        var sr = new StringReader(input);

        // Create an XmlSerializer object to perform the deserialization
        var xs = string.IsNullOrEmpty(elementRootName)
                     ? new XmlSerializer(objectType)
                     : new XmlSerializer(objectType, new XmlRootAttribute {ElementName = elementRootName});

        return xs.Deserialize(sr);
    }
}
```

Here is the unit test I have that is currently failing with 0 Associates when it should have 3.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DeserialiseMultipleAssociates()
    {
        // Arrange 
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
        builder.Append(
            "<subscription_product consultant_end_user_id=\"4\" farm_id=\"6\" farm_name=\"Farm Name\" farmer_end_user_id=\"5\" subscription_expiry=\"2014-01-01\" subscription_id=\"7\">");
        builder.Append("<associate_end_user_id>1</associate_end_user_id>");
        builder.Append("<associate_end_user_id>2</associate_end_user_id>");
        builder.Append("<associate_end_user_id>3</associate_end_user_id>");
        builder.Append("<product_id>1</product_id>");
        builder.Append("<product_id>9</product_id>");
        builder.Append("</subscription_product>");

        var xml = builder.ToString();

        // Act
        var reader = new SchemaReader();
        var subscription = reader.Deserialise<Subscription>(xml);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(3, subscription.Associates.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, subscription.Associates[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with an xml structure that contains the associates and products as listing elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" "encoding=utf-8"?>
  <subscription_product consultant_end_user_id="4" farm_id="6" 
     farm_name="Farm Name"   
     farmer_end_user_id="5" 
     subscription_expiry="2014-01-01" 
     subscription_id="7">
    <associates>
        <associate_end_user_id>1</associate_end_user_id>
        <associate_end_user_id>2</associate_end_user_id>
        <associate_end_user_id>3</associate_end_user_id>
    </associates>
    <products>
        <product_id>8</product_id>
        <product_id>9</product_id>
        <product_id>10</product_id>
    </products>
  </subscription_product>
```

Comment: That's initially what I thought however  I was given this xml by someone else to work with.  If it's the only way to go then I will get them to change it, however I was hoping to be able to not do that if I could.

Comment: you should get them to change their xml as it is presented poorly.

Comment: Ok, awesome.  That validated my thoughts.  Cheers.